# Value in table is not getting updated after updating $localStorage data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage, ng-storage

I have two components in AngularJS. One component `usersList` contains a table

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="..."><!--Contains code to repeat the entries in usersList localstorage object--></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

On page load, this component fetches a list of users with their details from an API and stores it in $localStorage. 
Other is a form `editUserProfile` where the values are edited and deleted

```
app.component("editUserProfile", {
  ...
  controller: function($localStorage, ...) {
    vm.$storage = $localStorage;
    // Do other things
    // Some event (edit) is successful, update the userslist in $localStorage
    vm.$storage.usersList = response
  }
})
```

So basically, I am editing user details and deleting users by making calls to the API, and when a successful edit/delete happens, I refresh the $localStorage value of usersList which is a JSON object.

Things totally works till the updating of the data, however the changes are not reflected in the usersList component. I am doing this to save calls to the API for just displaying the data. Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: What are $storage and $localstorage ?

Comment: I am using ngStorage. $storage and $localStorage are related to ngStorage.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uGYckz18K0Artusygbvg?p=preview) working.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage){
  $scope.$storage = $localStorage;

  $scope.$storage.entity = [];

  $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.$storage.entity.push('New entry');
  }

});
```

It seems that `$localStorage` should be passed in `$scope`.

> Pass $localStorage (or $sessionStorage) by reference to a hook under $scope in plain ol' JavaScript.

Your issue may come with `vm.$storage` assignement.

Comment: This works! But I overcame this problem by using a $watch on the ngStorage value i.e. usersList